# Importing wxPython pops errors

Tags: python, import, wxpython

Currently I am using Python 3.7, and Ubuntu 18.04. I downloaded wxPython from pip, but when I tried to import wx in my terminal, I get this error:

```
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/aleejandrof/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wx/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
```

later on, when I tried other ways like and "._core import" I received an error like this:

```
ImportError: /home/aleejandrof/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: pango_font_description_set_variations
```

After reading some posts here, I tried deleting the wx.py and wx.pyc files, which didn't work. The same happened when I read that downloading the main excecutable file would make the import occur with no errors, but it popped the same errors.

```
AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I am trying to run a GUI pipeline, which works with wxPython. I'm thankful in advance, if any of you has suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

When I made an environment of ubuntu18.04 using docker, ran into the same problem.

I had multiple `libpangoft2-1.0.so.0` files.
It seemed the problem was `/opt/conda/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0` was looked up.
To change the name of the file solved the problem.

```
find / -name libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
```

> /opt/conda/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
>   /opt/conda/pkgs/pango-1.42.4-h049681c_0/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0

```
mv /opt/conda/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 /opt/conda/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0-void
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try:

```
conda install -c asmeurer pango
```